# Update query with correlated subquery can't go through table alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery

I have this update query on my SQL Server

```
UPDATE BK_TT_DELIVERY_PLAN TDP
SET (PACK_TYPE) = 
            (SELECT OPD.PACKING_TYPE
               FROM TT_OM_PACK_DISCREPANCY OPD
              WHERE ISNULL(TDP.PO_REF,TDP.PO_NUMBER) = OPD.PO_NUMBER
                    AND TDP.PO_ITEM = ODP.PO_ITEM)
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM TT_OM_PACK_DISCREPANCY OPD
            WHERE ISNULL(TDP.PO_REF,TDP.PO_NUMBER) = OPD.PO_NUMBER
              AND TDP.PO_ITEM = ODP.PO_ITEM)
```

When I try to execute I always get this error:

> Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near 'TDP'

I try it on Oracle - it works fine.

Any workaround for this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't alias a table in the `UPDATE` clause, you do so in the `FROM`. As there is not `FROM` in this statement, then you do not give the table an alias. This would, however, mean that you would have to change all the aliases in the query to the table's name:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.BK_TT_DELIVERY_PLAN
   SET (PACK_TYPE) = 
            (SELECT OPD.PACKING_TYPE
               FROM TT_OM_PACK_DISCREPANCY OPD
              WHERE ISNULL(BK_TT_DELIVERY_PLAN.PO_REF,BK_TT_DELIVERY_PLAN.PO_NUMBER) = OPD.PO_NUMBER
                    AND BK_TT_DELIVERY_PLAN.PO_ITEM = ODP.PO_ITEM)
 WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
         FROM TT_OM_PACK_DISCREPANCY OPD
              WHERE ISNULL(BK_TT_DELIVERY_PLAN.PO_REF,BK_TT_DELIVERY_PLAN.PO_NUMBER) = OPD.PO_NUMBER
                    AND BK_TT_DELIVERY_PLAN.PO_ITEM = ODP.PO_ITEM);
```

Therefore using a `FROM` is likely a better idea, and then you reference the alias in the `UPDATE` clause:

```sql
UPDATE TDP
   SET (PACK_TYPE) = 
            (SELECT OPD.PACKING_TYPE
               FROM TT_OM_PACK_DISCREPANCY OPD
              WHERE ISNULL(TDP.PO_REF,TDP.PO_NUMBER) = OPD.PO_NUMBER
                    AND TDP.PO_ITEM = ODP.PO_ITEM)
FROM dbo.BK_TT_DELIVERY_PLAN TDP
WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
         FROM TT_OM_PACK_DISCREPANCY OPD
              WHERE ISNULL(TDP.PO_REF,TDP.PO_NUMBER) = OPD.PO_NUMBER
                    AND TDP.PO_ITEM = OPD.PO_ITEM);
```

---

Separate note, you shouldn't use `ISNULL` is the `WHERE` (or `ON`), as it causes the query to become non-SARGable. Use proper boolean logic. It also seems, as well, that this could be made far smaller with a `JOIN` and not 2 subqueries.

```sql
UPDATE TDP
SET PACK_TYPE = OPD.PACKING_TYPE
FROM dbo.BK_TT_DELIVERY_PLAN TDP
     JOIN TT_OM_PACK_DISCREPANCY OPD ON (TDP.PO_REF = OPD.PO_NUMBER 
                                     OR  (TDP.PO_REF IS NULL AND TDP.PO_NUMBER = OPD.PO_NUMBER))
                                    AND TDP.PO_ITEM = OPD.PO_ITEM;
```

Comment: Using your second query it returns:  The multi-part identifier "ODP.PO_ITEM" could not be bound.

Comment: As Gordon just demonstrated with their edit, @Syns , that was indeed a typographical error in your original code. YOu had `AND TDP.PO_ITEM = ODP.PO_ITEM` but aliased the object `TT_OM_PACK_DISCREPANCY` as  `OPD`, not `ODP`; hence the error.

Comment: @lamu oh darn, I didn't notice the typograpic error. my bad. thanks for correction

Comment: @gordon-linoff thank you, it's the new insight for me, I'll use the 3rd query,

Answer (score 0):

Simple query, please follow below query. Where use joined query result and update records.

```
UPDATE TDP
SET TDP.PACK_TYPE = OPD.PACKING_TYPE
FROM dbo.BK_TT_DELIVERY_PLAN TDP
LEFT OUTER JOIN TT_OM_PACK_DISCREPANCY OPD ON ISNULL(TDP.PO_REF,TDP.PO_NUMBER) = OPD.PO_NUMBER AND TDP.PO_ITEM = ODP.PO_ITEM
WHERE OPD.PACKING_TYPE IS NOT null
```